# How to correctly create a new BSON Binary UUID to store on a Mongo database?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, uuid

I've overriden the `_id` field on a Mongo model mapping on my Ruby application to be of the type `BSON::Binary`.

I am trying to create a new `BSON::Binary` instance from a UUID String using this approach:

```
BSON::Binary.new uuid, BSON::Binary::SUBTYPES[:uuid]
```

However, I get `BSON::Binary::InvalidType` as result.

I have also tried types `:uuid_old`, `:generic` and using `BSON::Binary::TYPES` instead, to no success..

So the question is: what is the correct way of converting a UUID to Binary to store on Mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer while typing the question.

You don't need to pass the constant, just the symbol. Like this:

```
BSON::Binary.new uuid, :uuid
```